# VSCode extensions,C language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently studying C in Open University and i'm using VSCode to write my practical codes.What I'm looking for is,if there is any extension similar to **GraphViz** or **Graph Buddy** for visualization of what my code does or how it works for VSCode compiler for C language.I looked into many things without finding a solution.Any advise?

Comment: GraphViz is a library for drawing... well, graphs.  It doesn't diagram code of any kind.  Not quite sure what you were expecting.  There are many ways to visualize code; at your level of expertise a flowchart is probably the best option.  Have a look here: http://algoview.sourceforge.net/

Comment: this is nice but there is no download button anywhere.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, as it's asking for a software instead of a programming question. Have a look at [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.